# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Permission denied to access property "handleEvent"

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

When trying to click on a link I get the following:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Permission denied to access property "handleEvent"
from [remote server] https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/admin-1281904798962f996c66cecd685ab47c.js:11:in `unknown'
```

Here's the code:

```
$browser.elements(css: "a.btn:nth-child(3)")[0].click
```

The funny thing is that when I try to do this manually with Pry, it works.

```
# Works
add_new_link_button = $browser.elements(css: "a.btn:nth-child(3)")[0]
add_new_link_button.click
```

I'm using `ruby (2.2.2p95)`, `watir (5.0.0)`, `watir-webdriver (0.8.0)`, `selenium (0.2.11)`, `selenium-webdriver (2.47.1)` and `Firefox (40.0.3)`. I've also tried it with `Firefox (36.0)`.

Any ideas on what to try next?

**Update:**

I've just tried with `Firefox 35.0` and it works. So this seems to be a Firefox/selenium compatibility issue.

Comment: unrelated to the actual question, but why are you doing `$browser.elements(css: "a.btn:nth-child(3)")[0].click` instead of `$browser.element(css: "a.btn:nth-child(3)").click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a compatibility issue with Firefox and Selenium. I've tried it with Firefox 35.0 and that did work.